# How can I lock editing permissions in Google Sheets using Google Scripts, based on cell colour?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working with several Google Sheets which are colour coded, and am trying to lock all cells of a specific colour (like pink). The idea is for these cells to be automatically filled because of the formulae they contain, but not be edited by anyone.

I am super new to Google Scripts and am trying to use the ClassProtection. but if anyone already has experience in implementing a similar solution, I would be super grateful for your suggestions. I suppose I will have to go into each sheet and integrate the same Google script so that all pink cells across all sheets are locked in a similar way.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The following script can protect certain ranges and you can define to select the ranges in various sheets as per your requirement.

```js
function script() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var lastrow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var lastcolumn = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var ranges = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, lastrow, lastcolumn).getBackground()
  var protection = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().protect();
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < lastcolumn; j++) {
      if (ranges[i][j] == 'Pink') {  //any color code
        protection.setUnprotectedRanges([spreadsheet.getRange(i, j)])
          .removeEditors(['user1@domain.com', 'user2@domain.com']);
        protection.addEditor('user0@domain.com');
      }
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

Comment: You are only retrieving the background color of the first cell in the sheet (you should use `getBackgrounds` instead), this cannot work. Also, you are not iterating through all sheets in the spreadsheet. Also, you are protecting the full sheet and **unprotecting** the pink cell. That's the opposite of what the OP wanted. Finally, there's no point in calling `flush` at the end of a script, the sheet will update anyway when the script finishes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You want to protect all cells in a spreadsheet that have a certain color.

#### Solution:

You can do the following:

- Loop through all sheets in your spreadsheet, using [Spreadsheet.getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) and [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- For each sheet, you have to iterate through all cells in the sheet, **not just cells with content**, since a cell can be empty and have the color you want to protect. Because of this, you'll need to know what are the last row and column in each sheet, not just the last row and column **with content**. To retrieve this information, you can use [Sheet.getMaxRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows) and [Sheet.getMaxColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxcolumns) (if you don't need to protect cells after the last row/column with content, you could use [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) and [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) instead).
- Once you know the dimensions of the range to fetch for each sheet, you can use [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) to retrieve the corresponding range and [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds) to retrieve the hex color code of each cell in the range, in a 2D array.
- After retrieving the 2D array with the background colors (called `backgrounds` in the sample below), you have to loop through this array. Two [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loops are used for that in the sample below.
- For each cell, you have to check whether the background color matches the color code you want to protect. In the example below, the code is `#ff00ff`, corresponding to the named `magenta` color. Edit this in the code if this is not the color you want to protect.
- If the color matches, the script will protect the cell. This can be done by first retrieving the cell, using the `for` loop counter indexes (`i`, `j`) and [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)), and then calling [Range.protect()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect()) and removing all the editors but the user running the script (you cannot protect the range from this user), as shown in the method reference I just linked.

#### Code snippet:

```
function protectColor() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => { // Loop through sheets in spreadsheet
    const maxRow = sheet.getMaxRows(); // Get last row in sheet
    const maxColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns(); // Get last column in sheet
    const backgrounds = sheet.getRange(1,1,maxRow,maxColumn).getBackgrounds(); // Get cell colors
    for (let i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++) { // Loop through rows in sheet
      for (let j = 0; j < backgrounds[i].length; j++) { // Loop through current row
        if (backgrounds[i][j] === "#ff00ff") { // Change if necessary
          const pinkCell = sheet.getRange(i+1, j+1); // Get pink cell
          const protection = pinkCell.protect(); // Protect cell
          const me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
          protection.addEditor(me);
          protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
          if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
            protection.setDomainEdit(false);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- Since it's completely unknown which cells are pink, the script has to individually protect each cell with this color. This is not very efficient, and if you knew there was a pattern for cell coloring (for example, if all cells in a row had always the same color), you could color a larger range at once, reducing the amount of times the `protect` process should run, and increasing the efficiency (see [Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)).